# Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: raspberry pi opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi

- Raspberry Pi3 ModelB
- OpenCV 3.0.0
- python 3.6.x

Cannot show image via openCV. ex) imshow() 
here is my source code.

```
def show_captured_image(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path, 1)
    resize_img = cv2.resize(img, (480, 320))
    xy_axis = cv2.flip(resize_img, -1)
    cv2.imshow("img", xy_axis)
    cv2.moveWindow("img", 0, 0)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

`(img:2984): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:`
occurs in this line.

please tell me the solution!

Answer (score 11):

Try executing `export DISPLAY=":0"` from your ssh session just before running the script. It should set your display to the one connected to the  raspberry pi.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But, not working.. I confirmd that environment variable changed.
```$ echo $DISPLAY
```
Returned same error.
```(img:1430): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0```

Comment: same issue, did you find why?

Answer (score 1):

in this case, you may have a headless raspberry pi, which has no display.  please check it, if true, it means rasppi is not able to show anything. you must it must show the display on your computer from which you are ssh'ing. for that you must disable the access control on your computer.

1. Open new terminal and type command **xhost+**
   now you have disabled the access control on your computer,
2. **now do ssh login on raspberry pi using command **ssh -X**  instead of just **ssh** ,now open the python-opencv application,it will work**

Answer (score 0):

Are you ssh'ing to the raspberry pi from another computer?  If so you will have to set your display to the ip of that computer your ssh'ing from.

DISPLAY (IP Address):0;
export DISPLAY